# What font is this and where I can find more akin to this style and what's the style name?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

[image]

What is the name of this font and where can I find more fonts of this style? I also don't know what kind of font-style this is (e.g. of others, Grotesque, Neue, Slab, etc).

Comment: You can find similar fonts by uploading a screenshot of the font [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator):

Answer (score 2):

### Playfair Display Bold

This font seems to be [Playfair Display Bold](https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Playfair-Display-Bold.font?text=Siap%20untuk%20mencoba%20resep%20baru)

---

[image]

Comment: What about the "t", "c"?

Comment: I was deceived by an evil font recognition website, haha! Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

## Transitional Roman

> Playfair is a transitional design. In the European Enlightenment in the late 18th century, broad nib quills were replaced by pointed steel pens as the popular writing tool of the day. Together with developments in printing technology, ink, and paper making, it became to print letterforms of high contrast and delicate hairlines that were increasingly detached from the written letterforms.

The transitional Romans are those that appear between the old and the modern ones. Its main features, in addition to the usual in each Roman typography, are:

- Construction based on an orthogonal grid
- The o axis is at 90º unlike the old one that is slanted
- The serif ends at 90º or 0º
- The serif is thinner than the old romans but not a hair line like the modern romans
- The stroke modulation contrast is more accentuated

[image: o axis]

[image: contrast]

Other classical Transitional Romans are: Baskerville, Bookman, Caslon, Cheltenham, Kepler,  Times New Roman.

More info about Roman Typography classification in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113547/120647)

---

[Playfair Display](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Playfair+Display) via Google Fonts

[image]